# Making transaction using ERC-721

Tags: web3js, erc-721, openzeppelin

I'm new on web3, I want to create a code that can buy an item from a store using erc20 and erc721, I'm still confused about how can I do it I did so many searches on youtube and google and still don't have a clear idea.
I want to make like the following [transaction `0xf45589ed29f6cb075a1254716db7e2245b6093ab60f3794c6d46c4818e5beaa8`](https://explorer.roninchain.com/tx/0xf45589ed29f6cb075a1254716db7e2245b6093ab60f3794c6d46c4818e5beaa8).
I don't know if should I use the safeTransferFrom using openzeppelin, or should I use a specific method on Web3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You touch more than one topic. web3 and solidity.

You could transfer tokens using IERC20 interface of a ERC20 token in your smart contract.

safeTransferFrom is in ERC721, to send tokenid (nft) to another contract. eg.

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721-safeTransferFrom-address-address-uint256-

Good start and I recommend you to do more examples.

Comment: check my answer here,  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109785/erc721-approve-smart-contract-and-send-transaction-from-it/109807#109807